# BeanRegistrationExcludeFilter Class not found Exception in SpringBoot 3.1 .4 during serving restart

Tags: spring-boot, java-17

Using Springboot 3.1.4. And Running the application getting class not found exception BeanRegistrationExcludeFilter.
Is this Springboot 3.1.4 known issue. Can someone tell the workaround or any fix for this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:449)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:431)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:266)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:245)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.fis.mbp.api.process.rate.ProcessRateDsmApplication.main(ProcessRateDsmApplication.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/aot/BeanRegistrationExcludeFilter
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:442)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationExcludeFilter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 20 more
```

I am using JDK17 and STS 4.20.1 tool

Comment: What version of `spring-beans` do you have on the classpath? It would appear to be too old such that it doesn't contain `org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationExcludeFilter` which is new in Spring Framework 6.0.

Comment: Upgrading `spring-beans` fixed the issue